# files from sub-subdirectories?

Tags: linux, shell

In one directory (mydir),I have several directories (dir1, dirt,gatr,batr). And inside those subdirectories I have other sub-subdirectories, for instance for dir1 (ber,ang,des). Finally, there files inside those sub-subdirectories

```
Example:
 Mydir >> dir1 >> ber>> file1, file2,file3
I need this:
 Mydir >> dir1 >>  ber,file1, file2,file3
```

What I need is for each directory in (mydir), move all files from sub-subdirectories (ber) to subdirectories (e.g. dir1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `execdir` will execute the command *in the directory where the file was found*:

```
find $PWD/Mydir/*/*/* -execdir mv {} .. \;
```